Mouse events offset when using SKTransformNode in SpriteKit
I am using an SKTransformNode to transform my sprites into orthographic space. However, this seems to cause mouse events (and touch events) to occur in the wrong place.
Below I have a minimal example where I add a grid of SKShapeNode sprites into an SKTransformNode and then detect which of the nodes are touched in a mouseUp event. For debugging purposes the following is done:

The touched sprite is outlined
A filled square is added where the mouseUp event occurred in the game scene space
A stroked square is added where the mouseUp event occurred in the orthographic space.

As you can see from the screenshot, the event in orthographic space is offset from the place I actually clicked. How can I click on sprites in orthographic space without this offset?
I have tried using the mouseUp event within a subclass of the sprites but the same offset occurs.


class GameScene: SKScene {
    var orthographicSpace: SKTransformNode?
    
    class func newGameScene() -> GameScene {
        guard let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") as? GameScene else {
            print("Failed to load GameScene.sks")
            abort()
        }
        
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        
        return scene
    }
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        orthographicSpace = SKTransformNode()
        orthographicSpace?.zRotation = .pi / 4
        orthographicSpace?.xRotation = .pi / 4 // This causes the problem
        self.addChild(orthographicSpace!)
        
        addNodes(parent: orthographicSpace!)
    }
    
    func addNodes(parent: SKNode)
    {
        let scale = 100
        for x in 0..<10 {
            for y in 0..<10 {
                let node = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: scale, height: scale), cornerRadius: 10)
                node.fillColor = .red
                node.lineWidth = 10.0
                node.strokeColor = .black
                node.position = CGPoint(x: x * scale, y: y * scale)
                parent.addChild(node)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {

        let color = NSColor(calibratedRed: .random(in: 0..<1), green: .random(in: 0..<1), blue: .random(in: 0..<1), alpha: 1)
        let locationInOrthographicSpace = event.location(in: orthographicSpace!)
        let touchedNodes = orthographicSpace!.nodes(at: locationInOrthographicSpace)
        touchedNodes.forEach { touchedNode in
            if let touchedNode = touchedNode as? SKShapeNode {
                touchedNode.strokeColor = color
            }
        }
        
        let clickInOrthographicSpace = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
        clickInOrthographicSpace.strokeColor = color
        clickInOrthographicSpace.lineWidth = 3
        clickInOrthographicSpace.position = locationInOrthographicSpace
        orthographicSpace!.addChild(clickInOrthographicSpace)
        
        let locationInSceneSpace = event.location(in: self)
        let clickInSceneSpace = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
        clickInSceneSpace.fillColor = color
        clickInSceneSpace.position = locationInSceneSpace
        self.addChild(clickInSceneSpace)
    }
}

